# What is the most painless way to add a newline to the end of a String (or &str) in Rust?

Tags: string, rust

I have some user input (String) and intend to write it to a file, and am trying to figure out how to separate all writings to said file by newlines.

```rust
let my_string = "my user input";
write_to_file(my_string);
```

I don't think it's best practice to add a separate write for the newline (`file.write_all("\n".as_bytes())`) in my `write_file()` function but after trying to concatenate with the format macro (`format!("{}\n", my_string)`) and some pathetic attempts at messing with ownership I'm still unable to add newlines in a "proper" way (although maybe there isn't one, due to the way Rust is built).

Edit: I'm not using a BufWriter and just interfacing directly with std::fs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing to a [`File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) or anything else implementing the [`Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html) trait, you can simply use the [`writeln!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.writeln.html) macro:

```rust
use std::io::Write;
fn main() {
    let mut write_vec: Vec<u8> = vec!();

    // using a boxed Write trait object here to show it works for any Struct impl'ing Write
    // you may also use a std::fs::File here
    let mut write: Box<&mut dyn Write> = Box::new(&mut write_vec);
    writeln!(write, "Hello world").unwrap();
    
    assert_eq!(write_vec, b"Hello world\n");
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6b670e8b42c61e2b8a3bcd7d0459ee82)

Answer (score 0):

Mutating strings is inefficient: if you’re steaming data to disk, just let the file system handle the “concatenation”. If all you need to do is write a line to a file with a new line at the end, you can just write a function to abstract those two steps into one.

That being said, I’m sure there’s probably a better way to do what you want to do.

Comment: So ```file.write_all("\n".as_bytes())``` is a fine way to solve my problem?

Comment: If this is a [`BufWriter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html), simply writing twice seems OK to me. However, if you are using a [`File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) struct directly, this will result in two syscalls (one for writing the stuff that needs to be written, one to write the newline) – that would probably be more expensive than some string manipulation, especially considering that appending a single byte may in most cases not result in a realloc. However, I did not test this theory, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: That's a good point sk_pleasant. Using `writeln!` is a great choice. @justapieceofhuman you'd have to run benchmarks to figure out which one is actually more performant. That being said, you should first make your program correct, then worry about code elegance. Once your code is correct and elegant, then you can make it fast. (Though at that point it is often fast enough.)